# Date and Time formatting from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar

I have formatted the timepicker and Datepicker data into the following formats hh:mm AM/PM and dd/MM/yyyy, and stored both the variables into sqlite database.

Now, in another activity I need to retrieve these values from the database, and pass a pendingintent alarm through alarmmanager.

My problem is that I am getting these values in the activity from database, but I can't figure out how to compare these values to current calendar time, and pass the pendingIntent like cal.getTimeInMillis().

I tried using SimpleDateFormat, but it catches ParseException: Unparseable Date

Can someone help me out with this problem? Thanks in advance

I have tried SimpleDateFormat like this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(" MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);
        try {
            cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dnt));
        } catch(ParseException e){
            Log.d(LOGCAT, e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: post what you have tried please

Comment: Can you update you question adding the code that you are using to parse your data to date object?

Comment: Edited with SimpleDateFormat code

Comment: Are you sure the date string you are trying to parse is correct? What exactly is the value assigned to `dnt`?